# Enabling shared Folders in SCO 5.0.7 on vmplayer

Tags: vmware, sco

I have installed SCO 5.0.7 on a VMware Player VM on the Fedora 9 host system. In VMWare Player, i found an option to share folders between Fedora9 an SCO in Virtual Machine Settings.

I enabled this option, but I could not get it work.  I check the `/mnt` directory in SCO to see if the directory shared in Fedora is mounted, but it is not.

Could anyone please tell me the proper procedure to share folders using VMware Player and SCO?

Comment: Is it possible in any way to share players between a SCO 5.0.7 running on VmWare Player and a linux host such as Fedora 9?

Answer (score 1):

Shared folders require a driver in the guest OS. Turning on the option in the VM configuration merely gives the guest *permission* to access shared folders. The guest might not know how to turn VMware shared folders into its notion of filesystem. According to [the documentation on SCO OpenServer as a guest OS](http://partnerweb.vmware.com/GOSIG/SCO_OpenServer_5.html), the VMware tools (which include the shared folder driver) are not supported under SCO.

You should be able to access host files on the guest by running an NFS server on the host, exporting the directory trees you want to share to the VM, and mounting those NFS exports in the VM.

Comment: Thanks Gilles. I was wondering if we could mount a USB stick onto the guest, and copy files to the USB stick. How is it possible to mount a USB drive to the SCO running on VmWare Player?